# Solr query, sort by child value

Tags: jquery, function, sorting, solr

I have a nested structure

```
{
"id":"prop_53451_43851",
"ss_type":"child",
"ss_id_parent":"prop_53451",
"fts_field_hols_prices_price":905.0}
{
"id":"prop_53451_43852",
"ss_type":"child",
"ss_id_parent":"prop_53451",
"fts_field_hols_prices_price":1240.0,},
{
"id":"prop_53451_43853",
"ss_type":"child",
"ss_id_parent":"prop_53451",
"fts_field_hols_prices_price":1297.0}
{
  "id":"prop_53451",
  "ss_name": "master",
  "ss_type":"parent"
}
```

And i have a solr query that return min price for each parent.
But my main query not sort by higest child min price. 
I have read that is possible to sort by function https://blog.griddynamics.com/how-to-sort-parent-documents-by-child-attributes-in-solr.

My main query

```
select?fl=id,score,price[subquery]
&price.fl=price,score
&price.rows=1
&price.q{!term%20f=ss_id_parent%20v=$row.id}
&price.fq=ss_type:child
&price.sort=price asc
&fq=ss_type:parent
```

my result

```
  {
        "id":"prop_53451",
        "score":1.0,
        "price":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
            {
              "price":905.0,
              "score":2.9103725}]
        }},
      {
        "id":"prop_53452",
        "score":1.0,
        "price":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
            {
              "price":785.0,
              "score":2.9103725}]
        }},
      {
        "id":"prop_53453",
        "score":1.0,
        "price":{"numFound":5,"start":0,"docs":[
            {
              "price":703.0,
              "score":2.9103725}]
        }},
```

I think that i must add sort={!parent...